# Counting rows in mySQL database using PDO & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, count

I know this question has been answered before, but I actually have an error when I use an the following:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=open', $user, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();  
}

$count=$conn->prepare(" SELECT * FROM `dictionary` WHERE word = ':input' ");
$count->bindParam(":input",$input);
$count->execute(); 
$no=$count->rowCount();
if( $no > 0 ){
    echo "no";
}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in... on line 18
```

I don't see where the error is, particularly because I based this code off an accepted answer.

Comment: Are you sure that your connection $conn is successful ?

Comment: I thought that `catch(PDOException $e)` would flag if it were unsuccessful...?

Answer (score 0):

try replace this

```
  word = ':input'
```

by

```
  word =  :input
```